# FXML: Include custom component

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have control that extends `HBox` called `TablePagination` that I created purely in code that I want to include in a FXML file, so when I do this:

```
<VBox fx:id="box" spacing="15" styleClass="sectionStyle">
      <StackPane>
           <TablePagination fx:id="pagination" StackPane.alignment="CENTER"/>
      </StackPane>
</VBox>
```

nothing appears. But when I do it in code like this:

```
pagination = new TablePagination(itemTable,items);

StackPane pane = new StackPane();
pane.setAlignment(pagination, Pos.CENTER);
pane.getChildren().add(pagination);
box.getChildren().add(pane);
```

My control gets rendered but not in center. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code version `TablePagination` is centered within `StackPane`, but nodes inside TablePagination are not. Call:

```
pagination.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
```

Note that `StackPane.setAlignment` method is static, and you sould call:

```
StackPane.setAlignment(pagination, Pos.CENTER);
```